libqmi conflict with NetworkManager and ModemManager
why user need to stop NetworkManager and ModemManager when using libqmi?
I looked at some answers that told me libqmi would be conflict with NetworkManager and ModemManager for interfaces, but how to saw it on the Linux?
I have run fuser /dev/cdc-wdm0 but cdc-wdm0 is not used by NetworkManager(NM is active and enabled)
enter image description here
is there any other methods(maybe other commands?) to see if the libqmi is conflict with NetworkManager?
